# Python fastavro incorrectly converting float

Tags: python, avro

I'm having trouble understanding an issue I'm seeing in using fastavro (and also regular avro) to convert numbers defined as float in my avro schema.  I'm sure it is related to datatype storage at a level I just don't understand.  In a nutshell, I pass a record into fastavro.dump, and then pass the result back into fastavro.load, and when values get beyond ~9 digits the conversion to/from does not return the same result.

```
import fastavro
from io import BytesIO

schema = {
  'name': 'Person',
  'type': 'record',
  'fields': [
    {'name': 'EmpName', 'type': 'string'},
    {'name': 'ID', 'type': 'float'}]}

origRecord = {'EmpName': 'BillyBob', 'ID': 1111000000}

buf = BytesIO()
fastavro.dump(buf, origRecord, schema)
avroMsg = buf.getvalue()

buf = BytesIO(avroMsg)
afterConversion = fastavro.load(buf, schema)
print(origRecord['ID'])
print(afterConversion['ID'])
```

The output looks like this:

```
1111000000
1111000064.0
```

I expect that the conversion introduces the .0, but that the values actually change has me baffled.  The difference between the two also varies from -63 to +64 as the input value changes (which may point to what is actually happening here).  Changing the type in the schema to double/long/int *appears* to correct the issue insofar as my testing is concerned.   Smaller values do not exhibit this behavior when using float as the type.

Comment: This is a well-known limitation of the [`float` (single-precision) data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). Note that the data types are specific to avro, not to Python.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that it's well-known, I did a lot of searching before I posted this question but found no evidence of a similar problem elsewhere.  I guess it's all about searching for the right thing.

Comment: I had the same problem when using Python float and simply changed the type in the schema from float to double.  Now the values in the Avro file have the correct precision.

Answer (score 2):

Look at avro specification https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html

*a float is written as 4 bytes. The float is converted into a 32-bit integer using a method equivalent to Java's floatToIntBits and then encoded in little-endian format.*

So the loss of accuracy is predictable.